# Create login for local Windows user on MSSQL (linux docker)

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, sql-server-2017

Is it possible to create a windows user login for MSSQL that runs as linux based docker image on the Windows PC (no Active Directory)?

```
CREATE LOGIN [PC-NAME\LocalUser] FROM WINDOWS
```

If yes, which configuration the docker image needs, to be able to do this? Currently I got the following error:

```
Windows NT user or group 'PC-NAME\LocalUser' not found. Check the name again.
```

Comment: Check out this post,most people use sqlauth with docker:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/01/30/create-a-container-with-active-directory-support/

Comment: The login with sql user works as expected. We have a lot of unit tests that login with the local user (build agent) that execute the tests.One option is to edit all tests to use a specific sql user. The socond option is the answer for my question :) (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MS Docs: Configure SQL Server 2017 container images on Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker)

> Eugene_Resnick Aug 18, 2017
>   Anyway to connect to the DB without using SA? Either a local account on the Windows host or through a gMSA on the host containers domain?
>   LuisBosquez Aug 23, 2017
>
> @Eugene_Resnick **Integrated Authentication is still not supported on SQL Server on Linux**. You can create a new login and connect to it like a regular installation of SQL Server. In fact, we recommend at least changing the SA password after it was first provisioned.

Comment: Thanks. So we would edit our unit test to be able to use docker images as test database instances.